# I'm getting errors that I don't understand installing NodeJS on a freshly installed Ubuntu that is otherwise blank

Tags: apt, software-installation, nodejs

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 a few days ago. My laptop is almost entirely blank. So I am met with confusion when I try to install Nodejs using [these DigitalOcean instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-22-04) and I get an error.

I do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nodejs
```

The second command gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  javascript-common libc-ares2 libjs-highlight.js libnode72
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/26.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 124 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 197872 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_16.15.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (16.15.1-deb-1nodesource1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.15.1-deb-1nodes
ource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp', which is also in pa
ckage libnode72:amd64 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.15.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am new to Ubuntu so I can't read this message, or at least I can't tell what's useful etc.

I found a similar error message using Google [here](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/1157) and I followed [this instruction on the page](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/1157#issuecomment-849595760).

```
// Delete the new package source.
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d 
sudo rm nodesource.list

// Update apt, fix the install, remove nodeJS and the nodejs-doc packages. 
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove nodejs
sudo apt remove nodejs-doc

// then use the instructions to install the latest node
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

But that gives me the same or a similar error

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  javascript-common libc-ares2 libjs-highlight.js libnode72
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/26.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 124 MB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 197872 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_16.15.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (16.15.1-deb-1nodesource1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.15.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/systemtap/tapset/node.stp', which is also in package libnode72:amd64 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.15.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any suggestions? Please & thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the nodejs version you are trying to install (16.15) it appears that you are not installing nodejs from the Ubuntu 22.04 distribution, where 12.22 is current.

Unless you have a specific reason to install the out-of-distro version, you could just remove the file you added to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` in order to obtain the 16.15 version, and then run `apt update && apt install nodejs` to install 12.22.

If you insist on the out-of-distro newer version, first remove the remnants of the Ubuntu default version with `apt autoremove` (as `apt` suggests), then try installing again.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` and then `curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -` + `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` worked for me, thanks. And,  I need version >16 for work.

Comment: Agree with pluto. I recently had this issue as well. zwets tip on using `apt autoremove` then all the install lines works.

Answer (score 2):

```sh
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_16.15.1-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb
```

[i have shared my installed screen shot here](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/1541#issuecomment-1509792077)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1292974)